# MVC client side error message not showing

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, annotations

I want to implement client side validation on my form, but none of the error message is showing when I put the wrong data.  Below is my model code:

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace LayoutProject.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public String Author { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My partial view:

```
@model LayoutProject.Models.Book    

<h4>Books</h4>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(d=>d.BookId)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.BookId)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(d=>d.Title)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.Title)
                @{ Html.ValidateFor(d => d.Title); }
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d=>d.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(d=>d.Author)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(d=>d.Author)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

View:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateBooks";
}

<h2>CreateBooks</h2>

<form action="/Home/SaveBooks" method="post">
    @Html.Partial("_CreateBook")
    <input id="createBook" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveBooks(Book book)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        //write code to update student 

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(book);
}
```

I have added the required scripts in my layout: validate and unobtrusive scripts.  But whenever, I submit the form, with the Title field empty, which is a required field, it goes in the controller and no error message is displayed.  Any idea what might cause this error?

Do I need to add all this scripts too:

```
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Remove `@{ Html.ValidateFor(d => d.Title); }` (not sure what you think that is doing). So long as you have not disabled client side validation and have included `jquery{version}.js`, `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` (in the correct order and with no duplicates) the client side validation will work fine

Comment: I removed '@{ Html.ValidateFor(d => d.Title); }' and I have added the scripts in the right order, but the error message would still not show.  I am using google chrome, the latest version.  The ValidateFor, I thought would verify if the field is empty or not.

Comment: Check your `web.config` file for `<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" /><add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />` in the `<appSettings>` section

Comment: Already checked and the settings are fine.  Really lost as to where the problem might be.

Comment: Are you sure you have not disabled javascript in the browser?

Comment: I do not see you setting any validation message. Maybe try this real quick.
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Your Error message here")]

Comment: @Stephen Muecke: Yep javascript is enabled.

Comment: Are the scripts are in the main view or layout (they should not be in the partial)

Comment: In the layout.  I tried removing them from the layout and put them in the main view, but still no error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are returning the wrong View in your controller when the model is invalid.
Change `return View(book);` to return View("the_actual_view", book);

Answer (score 2):

> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d=>d.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

Here you set the validationmessage to: "".
If your change it to:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(d=>d.Title, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

It should work.

**EDIT 1:**
Keep [Required] in your model.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see you set any validation message, so there is no message to show.  This might be the solution to your problem.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Your Error message here")]
```

And in your cshtml view, not to override the the ErrorMessage set above, do the following:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(d=>d.Title, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Comment: Nope, I want to use the default error message, not a customized one.  But still, I tried your solution and the error message still will not show.

Comment: this is wrong, when you do not provide an error message in the attribute, the default message will be used